# configuring Phusion Passenger for best performance with smart spawning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm trying to configure passenger to use smart spawning with ruby on rails but it just seemed to slow all my sites down? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

It's very frustrating when I visit one of my sites and it takes 4/5 seconds to load because it has to start a new rails process.

I'm not sure what I can do to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [PassengerPreStart](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPreStart) and [PassengerMinInstances](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMinInstances) configuration settings.

By default passenger kills off instances after a while, meaning the first visit to a site is slow.

These directives combined will ensure that there's an instance ready to serve a client.

If that doesn't help, you're probably low on memory or have too many sites on the same server.